# Python groupby, cumsum and max to calculate month-end balances

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that I have massaged to look like this.

```
         Date    Amount Month   Balance
0    9/4/2018  32000.00     9  32000.00
1   9/30/2018     29.59     9  32029.59
2   10/1/2018     34.05    10  32063.64
3  10/31/2018  -1000.00    10  31063.64
4   11/1/2018   1500.00    11  32563.64
5  11/30/2018     33.06    11  32596.70
6   12/1/2018  -2000.00    12  30596.70
7  12/31/2018     34.26    12  30630.96
```

I need to calculate the balance at the end of each month and the highest month-end balance. I have tried various combinations of groupby, cumsum and max, but I am not getting the expected results.

Here is what I have so far:

```
month_end_balance = yearly_df.groupby('Month')['Amount'].cumsum()
max_month_end_balance = month_end_balance.max()
```

I am expecting the month_end_balance to be:

```
9   32029.59
10  31063.64
11  32596.70
12  30630.96
```

I am expecting the max_month_end_balance to be 32596.70

Comment: Instead of `cumsum`, I suspect you simply want `sum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the `Date` column to `datetime`:

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Then :

```
m=(df.assign(cum_Amount=df.Amount.cumsum()).
  groupby(df.Date.dt.month)['cum_Amount'].max().reset_index())
print(m)
```

---

```
   Date  cum_Amount
0     9    32029.59
1    10    31063.64
2    11    32596.70
3    12    30630.96
```

**EDIT** Seems you already have the Balance and you are interested just to filter the month end dates, use:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
df[df.Date.eq(df.Date+MonthEnd(0))]
```

---

```
        Date   Amount  Month   Balance
1 2018-09-30    29.59      9  32029.59
3 2018-10-31 -1000.00     10  31063.64
5 2018-11-30    33.06     11  32596.70
7 2018-12-31    34.26     12  30630.96
```

Comment: When I run this code, I get an incorrect value for the October month-end balance (32063.64)

Comment: @b00kgrrl can you check the edit part and confirm? thanks